# read: not a valid identifier

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to write bash script that will run a command on certain fs events.
So far I have succeeded in building fswatch and configuring it, but I cannot get bash to split a string into an array, to then switch case (if that exists) all the different events that I am watching for.

I always get some form of `not a valid identifier` and I dont even know what that is supposed to mean.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

IFS=" "

fswatch -0 -xnr --event 2 --event 4 --event  8 --event 16 --event 128 --event 256 ./ \
| xargs -0 -n 1 -I {path} sh -c "echo {path}; read -a arr {path};"
```

```
sh: line 0: read: `/run/media/twiggeh/Storage/projects/Clone/client/src/script.sh': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: @DavidPostill that tools output doesn't seem to contain any useful information, its mistaking the replacement string for something else it seems

Comment: `read -a` is a bash extension, not available in `sh`.

Comment: @glennjackman: `read` is found in [sh(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh).

Comment: I think that there is something missing in the path `/run/media/twiggeh/Storage/projects/Clone/client/src/script.sh`.

Comment: @harrymc I really only wanted to read the file path as a string into the array. I've managed to do it with `arr=($(echo {path} | tr " " "\n"))` but I am still curious about why my first approach did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

The `not a valid identifier` message is telling you that you can't use a file path as a variable name (your code is expanding the `read` statement to something like `read -a arr /path/to/my/directory`. You're calling `sh`, which may not necessarily be a shell such as `bash` that even understands `-a arr` (`dash`, for example, would report `dash: 1: read: Illegal option -a`). Specify `bash` if you want `bash`.

However, I think you would do better to turn your code inside out (as it were). The following is `bash` code that will handle filenames containing not only whitespace but other strange characters (newline, etc.):

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r line
do
    # Split at the last space
    file="${line% *}" event="${line##* }"

    # Event and file are now separated
    printf "event=%s, file=%s.\n" "$event" "$file"

    # Put your case statements here
    # case "$event" ... esac

done < <(fswatch -0 -xnr --event 2 --event 4 --event 8 --event 16 --event 128 --event 256 ./)
```

The redirect from `fswatch...` allows your main while loop to remain in the parent shell's context, so that any variables you set in the `case`...`esac` part remain accessible to the rest of the script. Using the more obvious `fswatch ... | while ... do ... done` construct would put the `while` loop into a subshell, preventing any variables it might set from being available in the remainder of the script.